# ClassCastException when using a set of pairs

Tags: java, set, treeset

I would like to use a set of pairs in Java, but when I call `contains()` to see if it already contains a specific pair then I always get a `ClassCastException`. Is there a way to avoid this kind of behaviour?

It is instantiated like this:

```
private static final Set<Pair<String, String>> BLACKLIST = new TreeSet<>();

BLACKLIST.add(new Pair<String, String>("anytext", "anytext"));
```

Calling contains() here leads to following ClassCastException:

```
if (!blacklist.contains(new Pair<String, String>(localizedFile.getName(), key)))

java.lang.ClassCastException: .common.util.Pair cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
        at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
        at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
```

I use java.util classes instead of my own. Is there an elegant way to avoid to implement a new class pair which overloads common.util.Pair?

Comment: does Pair implement Comparable?

Comment: Can you share your `Pair` class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable: java.lang.ClassCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716790/myclass-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-comparable-java-lang-classcastexception)

Comment: The duplicate don't use a `Set` but the reason is the same and the solution too.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890542/creating-a-treeset-with-a-non-comparable-class-why-a-run-time-exception-rather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeSet uses the natuarl ordering of its elements 
unless you passed any explicit comparator to the constructor while creating the Set .

The contract says that all elements inserted into
the set must implement the  Comparable interface.Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable  `e1.compareTo(e2)` must not throw a
ClassCastException for any elements  e1 and e2 in the set.

You code is

```
  private static final Set<Pair<String, String>> BLACKLIST = new TreeSet<>();
BLACKLIST.add(new Pair<String, String>("anytext", "anytext"));
```

Since your have not passed a explicit Comparator to the constructor and neither your elements (Pair) implements a good Comparable you are getting a class cast exception while adding a element to the set.

My suggestion is 
  (i) pass a explicit comparator

or(ii)make Pair implements Comparable  as below

```
public class Pair<T1 extends Comparable<T1>, T2 extends Comparable<T2>> implements Comparable<Pair<T1, T2>> {
    T1 firstName;
    T2 secondName;

    public Pair(T1 firstName, T2 secondName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public T1 getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public T2 getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    // elements ordered with first parameter .you can make a better
    // comparable as well
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair<T1, T2> o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.firstName.compareTo(o.firstName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TreeSet` uses the natural ordering of its elements, and it seems to cast to `Comparable` to do that.

What you can do to make this code work is to give the `TreeSet` your own `Comparator` so it can use that instead of natural ordering.

```
Set<Pair<String, String>> blacklist = new TreeSet<>(
    Comparator.comparing(Pair::getFirst)
              .thenComparing(Pair::getSecond));
```

which will order by first, then second item of the `Pair`.

Comment: I cannot use Pair::getFirst in Java.

Comment: @pink_panda The exact method name depends on your `Pair` class of course. Also, on the Java version you're using; I'm assuming Java 8 or later.